# Lost ESXi root Password - How to reset it from iDRAC (v.7) at Hetzner

Tags: system-administration, password-recovery, esxi, vsphere, esx

How to reset ESXi root password from iDRAC (v.7) for Dell PowerEdge R720?
Is it possible?

Comment: Please share more info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per vmware [documnetaion](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1317898)

> `Reinstalling the ESXi host is the only supported way to reset a
>   password on ESXi.  Any other method may lead to a host failure or an
>   unsupported configuration due to the complex nature of the ESXi
>   architecture.`

Now if you can take the risk then check [ESXi - Reset the password for root](http://www.vm-help.com/esx/esx3i/Reset_root_password.php) . This use a Slax Linux Live CD to reset the password.

Comment: It deserves a try.
Thanks!